# Interesting problem about abc being a perfect power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For natural a,b,c this equality holds:

$a^3c^2+b^3a^2+c^3b^2=3  \sqrt[3]{(a^5b^5c^5)}.$

Show that abc is a perfect fifteenth power.

I got to this point so far in my problem. I tried to create a proof by contradiction. My intuition says the three terms on the left are equal, so I tried assuming the opposite. How is this one solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following.

> My intuition says the three terms on tge left are equal

AM-GM inequality confirms your intuition. So we have $a^3c^2=b^3a^2=c^3b^2=A$. Then $abc=0$ or $ac^2=b^3$ and $ba^2=c^3$. Then $a^7c^2=a^6b^3=c^9$, so $a=c$ and $b=c$. 
But there we should stop, because, for instance, if $a=b=c=2$ then the condition of the question is satisfied, but  $abc=8$ is not a perfect fifteenth power.

Comment: Beauty in its essence

Comment: In the problem there was a condition that gcd(a,b,c)=1. So they are all 1.

Comment: Though it would be cool if i had the intuition to pull am hm out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $a,b,c$ are natural, we always have:
$$a^3c^2+b^3a^2+c^3b^2\geq 3\cdot (a^5b^5c^5)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$

Equality holds only when $a^3b^2,b^3a^2,c^3b^2$ are equal.